# Two google charts on one page, one keeps getting clipped

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

Before I put two google charts on one page, I didn't have a problem.

But not it seems as if at least one keeps getting clipped.

I took the code and put it into js fiddle, and it's still happening so it's not my css or json that's causing a problem.

I'm new to javascript so I'm probably doing something wrong. I tried creating a different function for the second chart, but that didn't help.

HINT: somtimes it doesn't happen, but most of the time, at least one chart is "clipped".  OR the bars just Disappear.

`svg doesn't play nice here, visit js fiddle`

http://jsfiddle.net/ameshkin/ygdng1w5/

Comment: What do you mean by "clipped"?  Which browser(s) does it happen on?

Comment: The entire chart appears, and then white space takes over the bottom portion of the chart.

The second chart at the bottom, gets clipped on the right hand side.

And it happens on all browsers :(

Comment: I'm not seeing that. In Chrome or Firefox.  The fiddle works fine AFAICS.

Comment: OK.

I should maybe check on other computers.  It's definitely happening for me but sometimes the charts work fine. It's always one or the other.

I can post a screen print perhaps.

Comment: I was leaving out the width in the JSON that feeds the charts the options.

After putting in a width of 1200 pixels, it seems to work much better.

How would I be able to tell the chart to be 100%  ??

Comment: actually it's still happening. 

It just seems to work sometimes.  It's very strange but I suspect it's my javascript. :(

And 100% seems to work fine in the options.

Comment: In your fiddle you just posted the raw output, so we won't be experiencing the same problems (which is why it probably works fine for us) Could you make a fiddle with the source code?